# How do I get only messages containing event in microsoft graph api?

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api

I have tried many combinations to filter out messages, I only need messages containing events,
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=meetingMessageType ne null`,
but it does not work and meetingMessageType property only exists for eventMessage and not on Microsoft.OutlookServices.Message, is there any way to only fetch eventMessages with event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meeting message fields (meetingMessageType, responseType, isOutOfDate, etc.) need the prefix `microsoft.graph.eventMessage/` when using `$select` or `$filter`.

The following query works, but poorly:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=microsoft.graph.eventMessage/meetingMessageType ne 'none'
```

Caveats based on quick testing:

- This executes very inefficiently.
- This returns results in the wrong order (by meetingMessageType, then by date ascending, rather than by date descending).
- This also returns undeliverable notifications, which do not have the meetingMessageType property at all.

It appears the best approach is to retrieve all messages and filter by meetingMessageType client-side.